# How to fix several (permission related) exceptions with Lift and Jetty?

Tags: java, scala, jetty, lift, logback

I'm trying to deploy a small Lift webapp to a Jetty container but I get several exceptions. I pasted a small excerpt of the stack trace below. I can provide the full stack trace if needed. I goggled all three problems but I couldn't find anything useful to solve it.

I created my app.war file in sbt with the package command and just dropped the web archive inside Jetty webapps folder.

~$ whereis jetty8
jetty8: /etc/jetty8 /usr/share/jetty8

```
~$ ls -al /usr/share/jetty8/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 4096 Feb 28 13:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 107 root root 4096 Feb 28 16:12 ..
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   20 Jul 30  2013 contexts -> /etc/jetty8/contexts
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   11 Jul 30  2013 etc -> /etc/jetty8
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   25 Jul 30  2013 javadoc -> ../doc/libjetty8-java/api
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Feb 28 13:25 lib
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   15 Jul 30  2013 logs -> /var/log/jetty8
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Feb 28 13:25 resources
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   40 Jul 30  2013 start.jar -> ../java/jetty8-start-8.1.3.v20120416.jar
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   23 Jul 30  2013 webapps -> /var/lib/jetty8/webapps
```

I'm using Scala 2.10.3, Lift 2.6-M2, SBT 0.13.1, Jetty 8.1.3.v20120416 and Java 8 on Linaro Ubuntu Server 13.10.

Stacktrace[excerpt]:

```
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[FILE] - openFile(console.devmode.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: console.devmode.log (Permission denied)
at java.io.FileNotFoundException: console.devmode.log (Permission denied)
at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)

ERROR net.liftweb.db.StandardDBVendor - Unable to get database connection. url=jdbc:h2:lift_proto.db;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: IO Exception: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/jetty8/lift_proto.db.lock.db (Permission denied)"; "/usr/share/jetty8/lift_proto.db.lock.db" [90031-167]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329) ~[h2-1.3.167.jar:1.3.167]
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:158) ~[h2-1.3.167.jar:1.3.167]

ERROR n.liftweb.http.provider.HTTPProvider - Failed to Boot! Your application may not run properly
java.lang.NullPointerException: Looking for Connection Identifier ConnectionIdentifier(lift) but failed to find either a JNDI data source with the name lift or a lift connection manager with the correct name
at net.liftweb.db.DB$$anonfun$newConnection$2.apply(DB.scala:190) ~[lift-db_2.10-2.6-M2.jar:2.6-M2]
```

Comment: what user are you trying to run jetty as?

Comment: @barnesjd I created a temp folder in JETTY_HOME and added a jetty user with useradd --user-group --shell /bin/false --home-dir /usr/share/jetty8/temp jetty. (~$ cat /etc/passwd => jetty:x:1001:1003::/usr/share/jetty8/temp:/bin/false) But still the same exceptions.

Comment: Do an `ls -al jetty8` in `/usr/share`.  Lift is trying to write in `/usr/share/jetty8`, but perhaps the `jetty` user does not have sufficient permissions to write there.

Comment: @barnesjd Ok, that's it. I solved it with the following command: ~$ sudo chown --recursive jetty /usr/share/jetty8. Now everything works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Have fun with Lift! :)